# Bug in Notification bar when earning a new privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, notification-bar

I have just crossed the 1500 reputation mark on MSO and so I have gained the privilege to edit tag wikis.

However, according to [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/membership-has-its-privileges/) the Notification bar is supposed to contain a hyperlink to "learn more" about this privilege. In this case I presume the hyperlink would take you to the [Edit Tag Wiki page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki) but as you can see from the screen shot below there is no link.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Still no link....
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, buggy html, was only an issue in chrome for some reason.