# Privilege name missing in alert

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, notification-bar

Shouldn't the privilege-gained alert message include the name of the privilege in it? It reads a bit strangely as it is.

E.g. "Congrats, you've gained the privilege — **vote up** and 8 other privileges" (or something similar).

[image: screenshot of missing privilege name in notification]

This would be something like [the alert messages in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67507/bug-in-notification-bar-when-earning-a-new-privilege).

I got this after clicking through from a sidebar ad on SO to a site I had visited (I think) once before.

---

(It turns out it was "create chat rooms" and it now looks like this:

[image: screenshot of fixed privilege name])

Comment: The privilege was use of the em-dash. Duh.

Comment: mmm dash.  I can't wait til I get &thorn;

Comment: It looks like the dash actually was the privilege name; normally it looks [like this](http://so.mrozekma.com/privileges-bar.png)

Comment: No, you got _the_ privilege. You know, the only one that really matters. If you haven't figured it out yet, maybe you're not ready for it, and we should revoke it....

Comment: @Pop - I assume you're talking about use of the SO ninja squad.

Comment: sorry, will try to sort this today, been busy building a new workstation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah ... this took me an hour to nail down ... the fix ...

```
update Messages set Text = replace(replace(replace(Text,'>learn', '">learn'), '"">learn', '">learn'),'privilege to', 'privilege &ndash;')  
from Messages
where MessageTypeId = 9
```

I guess that will learn me

Comment: Was that the original code?

Comment: @jjnguy ... the messages in the message table were corrupt due to a rename and missing quote