# The privileges notification banner still isn't quite right

Tags: bug, status-declined, spelling

As a result of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69360/privilege-name-missing-in-alert), the privilege notification banner now reads

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege – edit questions and answers (*or whatever other privilege -ed*) [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)

That still doesn't seem quite right to me. It's mixing up the definite and indefinite articles, and implying that there is a grand total of one privilege to earn on Stack Exchange sites (there are actually 23). Shouldn't it be either

> Congrats, you've gained a privilege – editing questions...

or

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege of editing questions...

**EDIT**
When I originally asked this question, I completely forgot about English SE. I've now [posted there](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/75889/24038).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Congratulations, you have earned the
>   following privilege: {0}

And if it's more than one:

> Congratulations, you have earned the
>   following privileges: {0}

Answer (score 0):

Some ambiguity here is unavoidable as the formatting is generic, and the titles may vary over time.

Also,

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege – edit questions and answers

It may be oddly worded, but it is a valid sentence, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Even just changing the `–` to `:` would make a huge difference I think.  If you get multiple privs at the same time does it use `–` there also?

Comment: -1, because "it is a valid sentence" is simply not true.